# Laravel 4 - form action route issue

Tags: php, forms

I have a problem with a form, and its route..

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
```

I have this:

```
{{ Form::model(array('route' => 'rrhh.cursos.store', 'method' => 'POST'), array('role' => 'form', 'id' => 'formulario')) }}
```

This is the route or action of the form.

```
Route::get('rrhh/empleados/{id}/cursos',array('uses'=>'CursosController@show', 'as' => 'rrhh.cursos.show'));

Route::post('rrhh/empleados/{id}/cursos/store',array('uses'=>'CursosController@store', 'as' => 'rrhh.cursos.store'));
```

I have these routes:

```
public function store($id)
{
    // Creamos un nuevo objeto para nuestro nuevo usuario
    $curso = new Curso;
    // Obtenemos la data enviada por el usuario
    $data = Input::all();

    // Revisamos si la data es válido
    if ($curso->isValid($data,false))
    {
        // Si la data es valida se la asignamos al usuario
        $curso->fill($data);
        // Guardamos el usuario
        $curso->save();
        // Y Devolvemos una redirección a la acción show para mostrar el usuario
        return Redirect::route('rrhh.cursos.show', array($data->cedula));
    }
    else
    {
    // En caso de error regresa a la acción create con los datos y los errores encontrados
    return Redirect::route('rrhh.cursos.show', array($data->cedula))->withInput()->withErrors($empleado->errors)->with('error_flag',true);
    }
 }


/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
   $empleado = Empleado::find($id);
   $cursos = $empleado->cursos;
   return View::make('rrhh/cursos/index_cursos')->with('cursos',$cursos)->with('id',$id);
 }
```

When I press the register button, it makes the action of the form and it gives the error and when I inspect the code from Google Chrome, the action of the form gives another URL

```
form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8080/demosigal/public/rrhh/empleados/1/cursos" accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form" id="formulario"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="2YSLitvrYvRSB6gYFHp7MAD4CXYKqwW2hg3aZZl6">
```

This must send me to `rrhh.cursos.store` but it sends me to the same page where the form is.  How do I resolve this problem?